# Puxar txtarea de editor html através de select

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Boa tarde,estou com problemas para conseguir exibir de forma correta o conteudo de um select dentro do editor html ckeditor.
Código abaixo:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Selecione a página</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="page" data-placeholder='Nenhum valor selecionado...'>
        @foreach($paginas as $paginas)
      <option value="{{$paginas->conteudo}}">{{$paginas->titulo}}</option>
      @endforeach
    </select>
  </div>
</form>


<button onclick="pegarValores()">Verificar</button>

 <script type="text/javascript">
 function pegarValores(){
    var texto = $('#page').text();
    var valor = $('#page').val();
    var conteudo = document.getElementById("txtArtigo").value = valor;
 }

 </script>

             <textarea id="txtArtigo" name="txtArtigo">
                    <div id="resultado"></div>
            </textarea>
</div>
```

Antes de carregar o editor html,eu clico em verificar e o código funciona mas depois não funciona,a idéia é que já funcione mesmo após carregar o editor.

Comment: A princípio para alterar o valor dos dados do CKEditor se usa [`CKEditor.setData()`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editable.html#method-setData)

Comment: Atualmente o valor do CKEditor com CKEditor.replace('txtArtigo').

Comment: Manda um pedaço do seu código em CKEditor